# Layout of Images in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to layout a collection of Magazine covers in a UICollectionView in which the background is a bookshelf.  I want it to have 2 magazines per shelf, and the rest to be seen when scrolling down.  Here is my code I have:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

      UINib *cellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"NibCell" bundle:nil];

    [self.collectionView registerNib:cellNib forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
    self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shelves.png"]];
}
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
    NSLog(@"1");
}
-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
       return [_allEntries count];
    NSLog(@"2");
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


     RSSEntry *entry = [_allEntries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *titleLabel = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
     UILabel *titleLabel2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:200];

           NSString *thearticleImage = entry.articleImage;
               [titleLabel setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:entry.articleImage] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon@2x.png"]];


    //    [titleLabel2 setText:entry.articleTitle];






    return cell;
}
```

I am using an XIB to create the collectionView cell.

When there are only 2 issues, it looks fine, but as more and more issues get added and you begin to have to scroll, they get quite off:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation of your UICollectionViewCell with paddings between cells could be kind a wrong. You can either play with size of images or set the size of cell programmatically:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout  *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
    return CGSizeMake(192.f, 192.f);
}
```

You can also play with paddings in Interface Builder.

You can also do this programmatically:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(100, 200)];
[flowLayout setMinimumInteritemSpacing:10];
[flowLayout setMinimumLineSpacing:10];
```